# How do you create a range in code and using those name ranges to find the average and then displaying that value into a certain cell

Tags: excel, vba

How do you create a range in code and using those name ranges to find the average and then displaying that value into a certain cell

I am trying my hardest!!

My Code:

```
Sub NameRanges()
Dim HourlyConsumption As Range
Set HourlyConsumption = Range("B2:B251")

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:="HourlyConsumption", RefersTo:=HourlyConsumption

Dim Replenishment As Range

Set Replenishment = Range("C2:C251")

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:="Replenishment", RefersTo:=Replenishment

End Sub
```

```
Sub DataAverages()
Dim AVGHourlyConsumption As Double
Dim AVGReplenishment

AVGHourlyConsumption = (Range("HourlyConsumption").Value) / ("HourlyConsumption")
AVGReplenishment = (Range("Replenishment").Value) / ("Replenishment")

Set AVGHourlyConsumption.Value = Cells("H1")
Set AVGReplenishment.Vaule = Cells("H2")

End Sub
```

Comment: `AVGHourlyConsumption = application.Average(Range("HourlyConsumption"))`

Comment: What about the worksheet? Do you know its name, code name, or index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add Named Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DoTheJob() ' rename appropriately!
    NameRanges
    PopulateAverages
End Sub

Sub NameRanges()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    ' Use the 'AddNamedRange' method to safely add the named ranges:
    AddNamedRange "HourlyConsumption", "B2:B251", sws
    AddNamedRange "Replenishment", "C2:C251", sws
End Sub

Sub PopulateAverages()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Note that this worksheet can be different
    ' than the worksheet containing the named ranges.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!

    ' Formulas
    With dws.Range("H1")
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(HourlyConsumption),"""")"
        '.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
        '.Font.Bold = True
        '.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
    With dws.Range("H2")
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(Replenishment),"""")"
        '.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
        '.Font.Bold = True
        '.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
    
    ' Values
'    With dws.Range("H1")
'        .Value = dws.Evaluate("IFERROR(AVERAGE(HourlyConsumption),"""")")
'    End With
'    With dws.Range("H2")
'        .Value = dws.Evaluate("IFERROR(AVERAGE(Replenishment),"""")")
'    End With
    
End Sub

Sub AddNamedRange( _
        ByVal RangeName As String, _
        ByVal RangeAddress As String, _
        ByVal WorksheetObject As Worksheet, _
        Optional ByVal ApplyWorksheetScope As Boolean = False)
    With WorksheetObject
        On Error Resume Next
            .Parent.Names(RangeName).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ApplyWorksheetScope Then
            .Names.Add RangeName, .Range(RangeAddress)
        Else
            .Parent.Names.Add RangeName, .Range(RangeAddress)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```